# How do I ask grep to return filenames that match a string while ignoring other strings?

Tags: awk, grep

I have multiple log files that I'd like to search for errors. These files also have a bunch of warnings that are helpfully called errors and other false alarms.

Right now, I have a godawful process to find the files I want to examine more closely:

```
grep error *.out | grep -v -e warning -e handle -e Sentry -e exitfuncs | \
awk -F: '{print $1}' | uniq
```

I suspect this can be more succinct, but I can't quite make grep do it. Help?

input:

```
file1.out
error. bad things happened.
error. warning, function deprecated
error. no really, this is bad.

file2.out
error. warning, function deprecated
error. warning, function deprecated

file3.out
error. warning, function deprecated
error. another bad thing here.
```

desired output:

```
file1.out
file3.out
```

Explanation of current command: 
grep error *.out returns every line from the sample files:

```
file1.out: error. bad things happened.
file1.out: error. warning, function deprecated
...
file3.out: error. another bad thing here.
```

grep -v -e warning strips out the warnings.
awk -F: sets the field separator to be the : and returns the first field from the input, which is the filename.
uniq de-duplicates the filenames, so that file1.out doesn't appear twice.

Comment: I suggest you let awk do it.

Comment: Please provide sample input and desired output. Make sure to include lines which should be filtered or pass each of the steps in your pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` is for doing `g/re/p` - that's all. For anything more complicated than that just use awk. You can replace your whole command line and print the file names with just this one call to awk:

```
awk -F':' '/error/ && !/warning|handle|Sentry|exitfuncs/ && !seen[FILENAME,$1]++{print FILENAME, $1}' *.out
```

but there may be a better approach depending what your input looks like and we haven't see your desired output yet either so I'm just guessing at what you wanted `uniq` to do wrt file names plus error values and idk what you wanted the overall output to look like...

Comment: Interesting. Looks like I need to learn a bit more about awk!